# How to select a custom block and region according to a view

Tags: 7, views, theming, blocks

I have a view / display page that needs to be displayed in a specific html - page format.
I did a `html--viewname.tpl.php` and `page--viewname.tpl.php` to display my view.

Within `page--viewname.tpl.php` I call `print render($page['content']);` to render my view.
All is working except that block.tpl.php and region.tpl.php are called by drupal system to wrap the view `content` adding several html tags (div)  that I don't want.

I expected to use function `MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables)` to ask drupal to use a custom block.tpl.php file, but within this function I didn't find the way to know if the function is called to render my viewn or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with a page view you can use the [views_get_page_view()](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_get_page_view/7) function, to get the view object for the current page, like this:

```
/**
 * Variable preprocessor for the block template.
 */
function MYTHEME_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
  // If we are on a views page display.
  if ($view = views_get_page_view()) {
    // If we are on the MYVIEW view.
    if ($view->name == 'MYVIEW') {
      // Add the view object to the variables for use in the template (if you need it).
      $variables['view'] = $view;

      // Use a custom block template for this specific display (if required).
      $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] =  "block__{$view->name}";

      // Add your block customisations for this specific view (if required).

      // If we are also on the MYDISPLAY display of MYVIEW.
      if ($view->current_display == 'MYDISPLAY') {
        // Add your block customisations for this specific view and display here (if required).

        // Use a custom block template for this specific display (if required).
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] =  "block__{$view->name}__{$view->current_display}";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks rooby, it is what I was looking for, now I don't understand why drupal is still calling the default `block.tpl.php` instead of my custom one set in the preprocess function. I'm still debugging to understand that...

Comment: Ok, in fact when `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] =  "block__XXX_YYY";`   drupal looks for template file `block--XXX-YYY.tpl.php`. Strange because I did the same for html template using `html--XXX--YYY` as suggestion and `html--XXX-YYY.tpl.php` as template file name without any problem. I will ask a question about that.

Comment: Underscores in template suggestions are converted to dashes in the template file name. Dashes are left as dashes.